# Change Silverlight transformation height direction

Tags: silverlight-3.0

Here's my xaml

```
<Button x:Name="btnTest" Width="88" Content="{Binding Value, ElementName=slSlider}" Height="{Binding Value, ElementName=slSlider}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ></Button>
<Slider x:Name="slSlider" SmallChange="1" LargeChange="10" Maximum="100" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Top" UseLayoutRounding="False" d:LayoutRounding="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="256" ></Slider>
```

Very simple stuff. Now what I want to do is restrict the button to only grow in an upwards direction, instead of growing both upwards and downwards. How's this done?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a [MinWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minwidth(v=VS.90).aspx) or [MinHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.minheight(v=VS.90).aspx). There's also MaxWidth and MaxHeight if you need them.

Although re-reading your question I am unsure if you're asking about limiting the minimum size of the button or if you actually are talking about alignment. If you're talking about alignment and you want the top of the button to grow out while the bottom stays in position, set the VerticalAlignment of the Button to "Bottom".

Comment: Perfect! It was the VerticalAlignment that did the trick! Thank you!